# While using scanf("%i",var) if the user enters a letter or just presses enter i get a problem

Tags: c, scanf

I want for my program to just ask again if the user entered a letter or just pressed enter.
I know that if the input is not a number scanf() will return 0, so i have been doing this:

```
int  variable;
printf("Please write an integer and then press enter: \n");
if (scanf("%i",&variable)!= 1) { /* ERROR CODE */; return 1;}
return 0;
```

But i dont want for my program just to stop if the input is not correct. So i tried this:

```
int variable;
do 
{
printf("Please write an integer and then press enter: \n");
} while (scanf("%i",&variable) != 1);
```

But the program will just start printing "Please write an integer and then press enter:" without stoping. Is there a way of doing this?

edit: Forgot the &
edit2: Thanks to everybody.

edit3: I have been looking into the functions. Will this code be correct?

```
char variable[10]; int var;
do
{
printf("Please write an integer: ");
fgets(variable,sizeof(variable),stdint);
} while( sscanf(variable,"%i",&var) != 1 );
```

I have tried it and it works but i post it here because i know im probably missing something.

Comment: Because `scanf()` does not consume the input it doesn't use. The user types `"foobar"`, you attempt `scanf("%i")` and the `f` never leaves the input buffer. **Use `fgets()` for user input.** `fgets()` consumes the input (removes it from the input buffer) :)

Comment: It should be `scanf("%i",&variable)`, not `scanf("%i",variable)`.

Comment: If `scanf()` returns EOF, you should break the loop. If it returns 0, you need to consume at least the character that cause the input to fail.  Often, it is best to gobble all the characters until the next newline (or EOF).

Comment: *But the program will just start printing "Please write an integer and then press enter:" without stoping. Is there a way of doing this?* And that's just one reason why using `scanf()` to read input from a user is a bad idea. Other reasons include errors leaving the input stream in an unknown state, making error recovery without losing input effectively impossible.  At least when using `fgets()` or `getline()` then `sscanf()`, if the input parsing fails you haven't lost any data, and you know data in the input stream is still available.

Comment: "edit3: I have been looking into the functions. Will this code be correct?" 10 is too small for all `int`. Use 13 or more to read `"-2000000000\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int variable;
do {
    printf("Please write an integer and then press enter: \n");
} while (scanf("%i", &variable) != 1 && scanf("%*[^\n]") == 0);
```

The second `scanf` discards characters till the `'\n'` character. The `'\n'` character remains, though it will be skipped by the first `scanf` on the next iteration of the loop.
The code has some defects but it will work in most cases. One defect is that, if `scanf` returns `EOF` without reading a character then the loop will exit but the value of `variable` will be indeterminate, which can cause undefined behaviour when used. This one is not difficult to cure. Another one is that, the behaviour is undefined if the user enter a number outside of range for `int`. So a way better approach, is to use `fgets` and `strtol` library functions.